# Spring Integration getting started

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to understand how spring integration works by trying to run the Geting Started guide in spring. 
(https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/#initial)
This guide walks us through the process of using Spring Integration to create a simple application that retrieves data from an RSS Feed (Spring Blog), manipulates the data, and then writes it to a file.

When I tried running the application my expectation was it'll write to a file 'tmp/si/SpringBlog' after reading the configuration mentioned in integration.xml. 
But that's not the case , the output file is not generated. So I am assuming that I have to write the logic to read from the rss feed and subsequently write it into an output file. Please guide me with the right logic/approach to accomplish the task to get started with spring integration.

My integration.xml is exactly like the one in spring tutorial, adding that too for reference.

I do not get any error while running but the output is not as expected.

### integration.xml

```
<feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" url="http://spring.io/blog.atom" auto-startup="${auto.startup:true}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer
        input-channel="news"
        expression="payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
        output-channel="file"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file"
        mode="APPEND"
        charset="UTF-8"
        directory="/tmp/si"
        filename-generator-expression="'${feed.file.name:SpringBlog}'"/>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to write any code. You seem to be missing the main component - the feed inbound channel adapter...

```
<feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" url="http://spring.io/blog.atom" auto-startup="${auto.startup:true}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</feed:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Did you follow the advice on the guide:

**When you’re finished**, you can check your results against the code in `gs-integration/complete`

?

Comment: Oh, your question wasn't formatted well so the inbound adapter was invisible. Edited. You should turn on DEBUG logging to debug your app.

Comment: after changing the path to directory="D://tmp/si" as is the file got generated. @Gary Russell, Thanks v much for your time!